# positiong DIV in ASPX file

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm going to make a big DIV centered horizontally in an ASPX file, I use following codes:

```
<body bgcolor="#33CC33">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<center>
<div style="height:580px; width: 890px; top:0px; bottom:0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">

</div>
</center>
```

it is positioned correctly, the only problem is that there is a small gap (about 10 pixels) between top of the screen and top edge of my DIV, but I want my DIV to start exactly from top edge of the browser screen, what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<body style="background-color:#33CC33; margin:0px">
    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:890px; background-color:#FFF">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            Page Content
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

S

Comment: Just thought I would point out, the position of the form tag isn't that important.  The main things to notice is the "margin:0" on the body (removes the space you where refereing to), and the "margin:0 auto; width:890px;" on the div (This is what centers it).

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting all margin and padding of body and div, that should do the trick.

Also, remove that `<center>` tag, it's been deprecated since the dawn of time. Really, use css for positioning.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work, I used:<body style="padding: 00px;" bgcolor="#33CC33"> and <div style="padding: 00px; height:580px; width: 890px; top:0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">, is it right?

Comment: No, it's not right. First, why in the world are you using "bgcolor" which is a deprecated html attribute. You're using CSS, do all the styling in css. Use the CSS background property. To reset all margin and paddings, you can use a simple css selector * { padding: 0; margin: 0 } you can put this either in a <style> tag inside the head (not recommended) or in an external stylesheet and link it using the <link> tag in the head. (recommended)